# Missing bytecode - following guide

Tags: tokens, remix

sorry for this stupid question - but I tried to follow this guide: https://medium.com/@mtrimble/watch-pasting-bytecode-and-adding-0x-290bb6dd9d65

However, when I press "details" in remix I do not get up the same alternatives as in the guide. Seems something is missing?

[image]

[image]

[image: It is supposed to look like this]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to the details of a different contract. You are looking at `ApproveAndCallFallBack`, not to the actual token contract. You must select the name of your contract using the box to the left of details.